# WiFly Shield - Bluetooth?

Tags: wifly, bluetooth

Will the WiFly Shield from SparkFun labs be able to connect to a Bluetooth network?

Answer (score 6):

No, definitely not. It connects to WiFi (802.11a/b/g) networks, not Bluetooth (802.15.1).

I don't think an Arduino Bluetooth shield is available commercially today. Your best bet is to either buy an [Arduino with Bluetooth integrated](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8255) or figure out how to connect a [USB](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8180) or [RS-232 Bluetooth](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8495) adapter.

By the way, on behalf of electrical engineers, I apologize for this 802.11.15.1.a.b.g nonsense. Collectively, we're bad at some things, and naming protocols appears to be one of them.

Comment: USB or RS-232 are bad suggestions. Simplest would be one with a TTL serial connection. Eg this one: http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9913

You can connect it directly to the UART pins on your microcontroller. 

RS-232 would require an interface chip, and USB would require a microcontroller with USB host, and lots and lots of complicated code to interface with it.